# Django, не отображаются изображения

Tags: django, python-3.x

Выкладываю содержимое
**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
...
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name=u'Изображение',height_field=None, width_field=None)
...
```

**views.py**

```
def BlogIndex(request):
    posts = Book.objects.all()
    template = 'html/book_index.html'
    context = {
        'posts':posts,
    }

    return render(request,template,context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin-panel/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('books.urls')),
    url(r'^books/', include('books.urls')),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(_PATH, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(_PATH, 'media')
```

**template**

```
{% for b in posts %}
<div class="col s2">
 <div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
                <div class="card__image border-tlr-radius">

                            <img class="border-tlr-radius" src="{% if b.images %}{{ b.images.url }}{% else %}default.img{% endif %}" alt="{{ b.name }}" title="{{ b.name }}" />

                    <img class="border-tlr-radius" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ b.images }}">
                    <img class="border-tlr-radius" src="{{ b.images }}">
                <img class="border-tlr-radius" src="{{ b.images.url }}">
                </div>
{{ b.images }}
```

Вроде бы все нормально должно  работать, а на выходе:
[image: Скрин 1]

Comment: А где у вас находится папка media, в проекте или в приложении?

Comment: Папка находится в проекте

Comment: Все дело в   url(r'^$', include('books.urls')), - если поставить доллар, то все отображается. Теперь нужно узнать, как лучше исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следствие:
В начале выяснилось, что для домашней страницы в шаблонах урлов нужно добавить доллар - url(r'^$', include('books.urls')), джанго отобразил картинки но начал материться на доллар, после видоизменения, казалось бы, обычной конструкции он с удовольствием скушал и отобразил страницу с картинками:
 url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex),

Answer (score 1):

```
r'^index/$'
```

Тут главное понять [принцип](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/http/urls.html) формирования выражений.

- символ **r** в начале строки — отказ от [экранирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) символов в строке.
- символы **^** и **$** обозначают начало и конец вашего выражения. Например, без указания **$** после index, для django эти адреса ничем не будут отличаться:

  ```
  /index

  /index/images 

  /index/images/logo
  ```

Да, он вызовет нужную нам функцию из views, но никаких параметров в неё уже не передаст.